# What's is the difference between required_with and required_with_all laravel validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I already tried have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation but still , i don't really get what's is the difference between :

> required_with_all

and

> required_without

Anyone can explain to me in detail what's the difference ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> **required_with_all :**

**Laravel Doc:** The field under validation must be present **only if all** of the other specified fields are present.

> **required_without_all :**

**Laravel Doc:** The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are not present.

**Example:**

```
$rules = array(
    'facebook_id' => 'required_without_all:twitter_id,instagram_id',
    'twitter_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,instagram_id',
    'instagram_id' => 'required_without_all:facebook_id,twitter_id',
);
$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
```

> **required_with:**

**Laravel Doc:** The field under validation must be present **only if any** of the other specified fields are present.

**Example:**

```
$rules = array(
'sell' => 'required_without:rent',
'rent' => 'required_without:sell',
'price' => 'required_with:sell|numeric|min:0',
);
```

Answer (score 4):

**required_with:**

The field under validation must be present and not empty only if **any** of the other specified fields are present.

**required_with_all:**

The field under validation must be present and not empty only if **all** of the other specified fields are present.

Note: Check bold text above.

For more detail see Laravel [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation#rule-required-with)

Comment: 'other specified fields are present.' , base on this ,
fields are present means the request have that field and it doesn't matter whether that field is emtpy or have value?

Comment: Please read carefully **"must be present and not empty only"** so value required