# Required_with validation for array

Tags: validation, laravel-5.8

I have a problem when I validate array with required_with validation. It is always showing even I input nothing . I got this error since two days ago. I want to check if one field insert value ,the other filed must insert value .If nothing insert , the other filed don't need to insert. Could you help me please?

This is Error I got even I input value or not . Is there any solutions for this ?
[Error Message Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaOtt.png)

Validation Request Code.

```
        'work_procedure[]'=>'nullable|required_with:times,work_points',
        'times[]'=>'nullable|required_with:work_procedure',
        'work_points[]'=>'nullable|required_with:work_procedure',
```

This is Model.php

```
  protected $fillable=[

   'work_procedure',
   'times',
   'work_points',

];
```

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44644016/whats-is-the-difference-between-required-with-and-required-with-all-laravel-val

Answer (score 0):

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-with-all

## required_with_all:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty only if all of the other specified fields are present and not empty.

## required_without:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty only when any of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

## required_without_all:foo,bar,...

The field under validation must be present and not empty only when all of the other specified fields are empty or not present.

> example

```
   $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'surname' => 'required_with:name'
   ]);
```

```
  $request->validate([
          'name' => 'required',
          'detail' => 'required|required_with:name',
  ]);
```

```
   Validator::make($request->all(), [
     'role_id' => Rule::required_with_all:foo,bar,
   ]);
```